# integrate sin(x).

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

OK. I have a doubt with this: I know $-\cos(x) + k =\int \sin x\,dx$ but doing
$\sin(x)=2\sin\frac{x}{2}\cos\frac{x}{2}$ I get $\int \sin x\,dx = \int 2\sin\frac{x}{2}\cos\frac{x}{2}\,dx $ if $ u = \sin \frac{x}{2}$ then $du = \cos \frac{x}{2} \frac{dx}{2}$ then $$\int \sin x\,dx = \int 2\sin \frac{x}{2}\cos \frac{x}{2}\, dx =4\int \sin \frac{x}{2} \cos\frac{x}{2}\frac{dx}{2}=4\int u\,du= 4\frac{u^2}{2}= 2u^2 = 2\sin^2\frac{x}{2}$$ then if $\theta = \frac{x}{2} \rightarrow \cos 2\theta =-2\sin^2(\theta)+k \rightarrow \frac{\cos(2\theta)}{2}=\cos^2 \theta -1+\frac{k}{2} $ if $k=0$, then $$\frac{\cos 2\theta}{2}=\cos^2 \theta-1.$$ Now, why isn't it a trigonometric identity? or Is it? Because I think that I found one.

Comment: This is the double angle identity for cosine. $cos(2\theta) = cos^2\theta -sin^2 \theta = 2cos^2 \theta -1 = 1-2sin^2 \theta$. I believe your value of $k$ is $1$

Comment: @Nicholas You can use LaTeX commands `\sin` and `\cos` to get the functions symbols rendered in upright font: $\sin$ and $\cos$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mistakenly equate indefinite integrals, which is wrong. Keep in mind that indefinite integrals are defined *up to a constant*, and that "fixing" this constant the way you do makes no sense mathematically (an indefinite integral should be thought of a set of functions, not as a precise function).

Answer (score 2):

You made a mistake. If $-2\sin^2(x) + k = \cos(2x)$, then plug in $0$ to get $0 + k = 1$.

Also, with $k=1$, this identity is already known. You didn't discover something new.

See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Double-angle.2C_triple-angle.2C_and_half-angle_formulae). Here you see that
$$
\cos(2x) = 2\cos^2(x) - 1.
$$

Comment: heee.. I know "I didn't discover something new" but What about for other values of k? why wouldn't they be a identity? It is enough to know that for some value of $\theta$ it isn't work . Everything is well done previously .

Comment: @Elll Because two primitive function to any $f$ can differ by a constant. So you prove that $\cos 2x = k+2\cos^2 x$ for one value of $k$. To determine the constant, it is enough to determine it for one point. Plugging in $x=0$, you get $1=k+2$ whence $k=-1$. (This all works if the domain of $f$ is connected, i.e., an interval.)

Comment: thank for explanation I thought that it was true for whatever value, but now I understand it.

Answer (score 2):

You should really **always write the integration constants**:

$$ \int\sin x\,dx = -\cos x + C_1,\qquad \int\sin x\,dx = 2\sin^2 \frac x2 + C_2.$$

Since $\sin^2 \frac x2 = \frac{1-\cos x}{2}$, we get that $C_1=C_2+1$.

Comment: The relation between the constants could also be set by plugging in $x=0$.

Comment: @Hurkyl I know, I commented in this sense in one of the other answers. This is not important; the important thing is that the constants are dependent on each other...

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use
$$\sin(x)=\cos(\pi/2-x)$$